# enable() and disable() emojionearea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to **enable** emojionearea on an editable div on an event trigger and **disable** it on another event trigger.

From [the official docs](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) I found that I should use `$("selector3").data("emojioneArea").enable();` and `$("selector3").data("emojioneArea").disable();`

but it doesn't work and if it helps from the beginning that I loaded emojionearea I get the below error in the console.

```
emojionearea.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: a.ajax is not a function
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the emojionearea, I fixed the issue by changing the jQuery version from 'v3.3.1' to 'v3.4.1'.